# Postgresql 10 arrays equality failure

Tags: postgresql, array

I am using AWS RDS postgres instance version 10.3.

Completly stuck with the problem.

I have a table like:

```
create table social_message(
  social_profile_id int8 not null,
  body text,
  subject text,
  conference_id int8 not null,
  created_at timestamp not null default now(),
  sent_at timestamp default now(),
  contact_ids bigint[] not null default '{}'
);
```

Problem is with equality check with contact_ids column.

SQL query like this shows problem:

```
 select 
   contact_ids, 
   '{23673159}'::int8[],
   contact_ids = '{23673159}'::int8[],
   contact_ids @> '{23673159}'::int8[] and contact_ids <@ '{23673159}'::int8[]
 from social_message
```

Which returns (skipping not interested rows):

```
contact_ids |int8       |?column? |?column? |
------------|-----------|---------|---------|
{}          |{23673159} |false    |false    |
{23673161}  |{23673159} |false    |false    |
{23673159}  |{23673159} |false    |true     |
```

Question is how it is possible that `=` operator does not work? I mean that if A @> B and A <@ B is true, this should be A = B - but it is not!

I am using doing inserts with scala slick. It is doing such prepared statements:

```
insert into "social_message" ("social_profile_id","contact_ids","body","subject","conference_id","created_at","sent_at")  values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Sample data for whole table:

```
social_profile_id |body   |subject |conference_id |created_at          |sent_at             |contact_ids |
------------------|-------|--------|--------------|--------------------|--------------------|------------|
42717             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 10:45:18 |2018-08-14 10:45:18 |{}          |
42718             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 10:52:48 |2018-08-14 10:52:48 |{}          |
42718             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 11:07:08 |2018-08-14 11:07:08 |{}          |
42719             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 11:09:06 |                    |{23673161}  |
42719             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 11:09:29 |                    |{23673159}  |
42718             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 12:06:32 |2018-08-14 12:06:32 |{}          |
42721             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 12:15:36 |                    |{23673170}  |
42721             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 12:16:29 |                    |{23673169}  |
42718             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 12:43:13 |2018-08-14 12:43:13 |{}          |
42722             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 12:45:56 |                    |{23673176}  |
42722             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 12:47:24 |                    |{23673175}  |
42723             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 13:26:28 |                    |{23673178}  |
42720             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 11:11:35 |2018-08-14 17:29:29 |{23673165}  |
42724             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 15:09:12 |2018-08-14 15:09:12 |{}          |
42725             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 15:14:41 |2018-08-14 15:14:44 |{23673182}  |
42726             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 15:17:17 |2018-08-14 15:17:18 |{23673185}  |
42728             |sample |        |3313          |2018-08-14 15:19:19 |2018-08-14 15:19:20 |{23673188}  |
```

**I localized problem to jdbc driver. When i do manual insert with psql select works like a charm. But when insert happened within scala code it does not selected.**

It is still not clear how it is possible to do.

Thank you

Comment: None of your contact ids have more than one element. why are you using arrays?

Comment: The point of the CREATE TABLE, INSERT statements and desired result is so we can see what you expect. It's not clear why "= operator does not work" or what "does not work" means in that context, and it's not clear what you want to happen when it works?

Comment: What about `contact_ids = ARRAY[23673159]` ? (or `ARRAY[23673159]::int8[]`). Of course as soon as you have multiple values you need to remember that arrays are not sets, so the order of elements count. Have a look at the related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647385/postgres-comparing-two-arrays

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ef37c4e0e6431570cb3b5b88de004950 It seems very odd. Did you mess with the `=` operator in your DB? I added a query to the fiddle showing possibly relevant operators. Do you see the same in your DB? Which point release of pg 10?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter i did not found anything in pg_operator (comparing to dbfiddle). I added version information on top.

Comment: @EvanCarroll i added explanation what i mean 'does not work'